# Transient analysis in presence of faults

Tags: dc, passive-networks, transient, switching-transients

While reading Shenkman's *Transient Analysis of Electric Power Circuits* I came across the following problem:

> ... This circuit represents the equivalent of a d.c. supply network. At the instant of time
> \$t=0\$, the short-circuit fault occurs at node ‘‘\$a\$’’ and when the short-circuit
> current \$i_{\text{sc}}\$ through the breaker reaches the value \$I=500 \text A\$, the circuit breaker
> opens practically instantaneously. Find the transient response of current \$i_2\$ after
> the fault. The circuit parameters are \$R_1
> =1 \text{ Ohm}, R=R_2
> =9 \text{ Ohm}, L_1
> =0.01 \text{H}, L_2
> =
> 0.45 \text{H}\$ and \$V_s
> =1100 \text{V}.\$ [image: fig2,18]
> First stage (the period between a short circuit \$t=0\$ and opening the circuit
> breaker, BR, \$t=t\$
> Since the circuit is divided into two sub circuits: the left one with current \$i_1\$ and the right one with current \$i_2\$
> , we shall obtain two time constants and two
> natural responses: ... \$i_{1,n}=A_1e^{−100t}\$, \$i_{2,n}=A_2e^{−20t}\$. The forced responses in these circuits are: \$
> (1) i_{1,f}= V_s/
> R_1
> =1100/
> 1 =1100 \text{A}, (2) i_{2,f}
> =0.\$ The initial conditions of the above two currents may be obtained by inspection of the given circuit prior to short-circuiting: \$ (1) i_1(0−)= V_s/\big(R_1+ (R2||R3)\big)
> =200 \text{A}, (2) i_2(0−) = i_1
> (0
> −)/2=100 \text{A}.
> \$

Now reading the above analysis for currents at \$t=0-\$ and \$t=0+\$ I could think of the following circuits, as \$t \to \infty\$, the circuit breaker opens at some point disconnecting the middle branch and the inductances are now in series, but the author suggests somehow the entire right branch is opened. I can't understand that.:[image]

Comment: <<< The forced responses in these circuits are: (1)i1,f=Vs/R1=1100/1=1100A, ... >>> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time and currents are in **log scale** ...

Here are the results of the simulation with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

V2 and V3 are "commands" for switching ON/OFF S1 and S2.
V3 short S2, than V2 opens S1 (when current ~ 500 A).

You can see that currents are at initial conditions 200 A and 100 A.
And in fine, current is 110 A. "High" transient at the breaker opening.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Transient analysis. I looked at the various situations.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]